# Magento DHL Domestic Shipping Not Working

Tags: php, magento, dhl

I have integrated DHL method into magento 1.9.2.4 and having one problem in it. my origin country is AE and when I try to order something in same country that is AE then DHL method is not working for all other countries its working. I have contacted DHL and they said the tag  must be N in magento log file. currently getting Y

Can any one tell me what original problem is and how can i edit  tag to N ?

Thanks Ahead.

Comment: hello, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Riccardo Yes I fixed it out.

Comment: I'm having similar issue, can you share your solution?

Comment: @Riccardo: Please share your complete problem. and magento's default dhl file. i can fix it for you.

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807915/magento-dhl-shipping-method-unavailable

Comment: Did you checked this with DHL ? what DHL said and then I will fix it. in my case they told me that isDutiable should be N.  so before anything ask DHL and then we will look into code.

Comment: I answer you in the other question

Answer (score 1):

ok here is complete answer to this problem that i have solved successfully.

replace DHL function here. app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php.  make sure you make a copy in local and then change.

in this file change this function to given below.

protected function _checkDomesticStatus($origCountryCode, $destCountryCode){
    $this->_isDomestic = false;

```
$origCountry = (string)$this->getCountryParams($origCountryCode)->name;
$destCountry = (string)$this->getCountryParams($destCountryCode)->name;
$isDomesticOrig = (string)$this->getCountryParams($origCountryCode)->domestic;
$isDomesticDest = (string)$this->getCountryParams($destCountryCode)->domestic;

if (($origCountry == $destCountry) || ($isDomesticOrig && $isDomesticDest)) {
    $this->_isDomestic = true;
}

return $this->_isDomestic;
```

}